# Array destructuring to swap elements

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using array destructuring to swap elements in array but it runs into infinite loop.

Whereas, if I save `A[i]` into a temp variable, it works perfectly fine. What is the reason for this?

```
 [A[i], A[A[i]] = [A[A[i]], A[i]];
```

Here is the full code

```
function swap(arr, i, j) {
  const temp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[j];
  arr[j] = temp;
}

function sort(items, newOrder) {
  // reorder items inline
  let i = 0;
  while(i < items.length) {
    // console.log(i)
    while (i !== newOrder[i]) {
      
      const temp = newOrder[i];
      //[items[i], items[temp]] = [items[temp], items[i]];
      [items[i], items[newOrder[i]]] = [items[newOrder[i]], items[i]];
      // swap(items, i, newOrder[i]);
      [newOrder[i], newOrder[temp]] = [newOrder[temp], newOrder[i]];
      // swap(newOrder, i, newOrder[i]);
      //console.log(newOrder)
    }

    i++;
  }

}
```

const items = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
const newOrder = [1,   5,   4,   3,   2,   0]

The question is to re-order items as per indexes in newOrder.

Comment: Oh, that's cute. I wonder if it has to do with trying to use `A[i]` as an index while also modifying it.

Comment: Could you please provide more context around this _code_. How is `A` initialised and what is the value of `i`?

Comment: I also just realized that it works in chrome dev tools when I try this on two-element array [1,2] like [arr[0], arr[arr[0]]] = [arr[arr[0]], arr[0]] but does not work on bfe.dev environment where I am solving a question.

Comment: It could be bfe.dev doing a polyfill

Comment: Phil:  Added the code in question.